# How to elegantly combine multiple Tasks containing options in ZIO

Tags: scala, scalaz, scala-cats, scalaz7, zio

I'm looking for the most elegant implementation of

```
import scalaz.zio.Task

def combineTasks[A, B, C, D](task1: Task[Option[A]],
                             task2: Task[Option[B]],
                             task3: Task[Option[C]])
                            (f: (A, B, C) => D)
: Task[Option[D]]
```

using

1. no additional dependencies
2. `scalaz-zio-interop-cats` and `cats`
3. `scalaz-zio-interop-scalaz7x` and `scalaz7x`

The solutions should generalize well to n arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting some help and doing research, I found the following implementations, that seem the most elegant to me so far:

**1. Using no additional dependencies:**

```scala
def combineTasks[A, B, C, D](task1: Task[Option[A]],
                             task2: Task[Option[B]],
                             task3: Task[Option[C]])
                            (f: (A, B, C) => D)
: Task[Option[D]] = {
  for {
    t1 <- task1
    t2 <- task2
    t3 <- task3
  } yield {
    (t1, t2, t3) match {
      case (Some(t1), Some(t2), Some(t3)) => Some(f(t1, t2, t3))
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

**2. Using `scalaz-zio-interop-cats` and `cats`:**

```
def combineTasks[A, B, C, D](task1: Task[Option[A]],
                             task2: Task[Option[B]],
                             task3: Task[Option[C]])
                            (f: (A, B, C) => D)
: Task[Option[D]] = {
  import cats.implicits.catsStdInstancesForOption
  import cats.Apply
  import scalaz.zio.interop.catz._

  Apply[Task].compose[Option].map3(task1, task2, task3)(f)
}
```

See [mapN over composed Apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55199931/mapn-over-composed-apply) for a related discussion.

**3. Using `scalaz-zio-interop-scalaz7x` and `scalaz7x`:**

```
def combineTasks[A, B, C, D](task1: Task[Option[A]],
                             task2: Task[Option[B]],
                             task3: Task[Option[C]])
                            (f: (A, B, C) => D): Task[Option[D]] = {
  import scalaz.Apply
  import scalaz.std.option._
  import scalaz.zio.interop.scalaz72._

  Apply[Task].compose[Option].apply3(task1, task2, task3)(f)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With cats, you can combine multiple options by using `mapN`. So this would work:

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

val o1 = 1.some
val o2 = 2.some
val o3 = 3.some

(o1,o2,o3).mapN((a,b,c) => a |+| b |+| c) // Some(6)
```

Olny thing left to do is just unwrapping Tasks and since they're monads, you can do:

```
for {
  t1 <- task1 
  t2 <- task2 
  t3 <- task3 
} yield (t1,t2,t3)
  .mapN((a,b,c) => /* combine a,b,c */)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was wondering if I could do something like `Applicative[Task].compose[Option].map3(task1, task2, task3)(f)` using `scalaz-zio-interop-cats`, but I couldn't get this into compiling code.

Comment: This works indeed - I was originally trying with UIO instead of task. There I get the error `Error:(75, 22) diverging implicit expansion for type cats.kernel.Order[A] ....`

Comment: What is this `Onlyc` thing in the middle of the code? And "Olny" is probably a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I must have accidentally typed it.