# mapN over composed Apply

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I know that I can compose `Apply` to work with nested structures, like in

```scala
def mapAll[A, B, C, D](o1: List[Option[A]],
                       o2: List[Option[B]],
                       o3: List[Option[C]])
                      (f: (A, B, C) => D)
: List[Option[D]] = {
  import cats._
  import cats.implicits._
  Apply[List].compose[Option].map3(o1, o2, o3)(f)
}
```

However, is there a way to convince the compiler to accept `(o1, o2, o3).mapN(f)` instead of `Apply[List].compose[Option].map3(o1, o2, o3)(f)`, so that `mapN` gets applied using the composed `Apply`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what `cats.data.Nested` is for:

```
def mapAll[A, B, C, D](o1: List[Option[A]],
                       o2: List[Option[B]],
                       o3: List[Option[C]])
                      (f: (A, B, C) => D)
: List[Option[D]] = {
  import cats.data.Nested
  import cats.instances.list._, cats.instances.option._
  import cats.syntax.apply._

  (Nested(o1), Nested(o2), Nested(o3)).mapN(f).value
}
```

(Note that you will need to enable the `-Ypartial-unification` compiler flag for the code above to compile. Alternatively you could add some type parameters, but off the top of my head I'm not sure exactly where they'd be required, and if you're doing anything with Cats `-Ypartial-unification` is pretty much necessary, anyway.)

You could also just make the composed instance available implicitly:

```
import cats.Apply
import cats.instances.list._, cats.instances.option._
import cats.syntax.apply._

type ListOption[x] = List[Option[x]]

implicit val listOptionApply: Apply[ListOption] = Apply[List].compose[Option]

def mapAll[A, B, C, D](o1: ListOption[A],
                       o2: ListOption[B],
                       o3: ListOption[C])
                      (f: (A, B, C) => D)
: List[Option[D]] = (o1, o2, o3).mapN(f)
```

This really isn't ideal, though—it's non-standard and extremely fragile (e.g. the type aliases are necessary to guide resolution).

In my view your best bet is just to write out `Apply[List].compose[Option]` explicitly and skip the fancy tuple syntax, but if you really have to have the fancy tuple syntax, go with `Nested`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I can't compile the first snippet though: `Error:(23, 42) value mapN is not a member of (cats.data.Nested[List,Option,A], cats.data.Nested[List,Option,B], cats.data.Nested[List,Option,C])
    (Nested(o1), Nested(o2), Nested(o3)).mapN(f).value` (I'm using scala-2.12.8 with cats-1.6.0)

Comment: Did you change the imports, or do you have other imports in scope?

Comment: I cannot compile https://scalafiddle.io/sf/31wU12L/1 locally with `scala-2.12.8` and `cats-1.6.0` or `cats-1.3.1` (as used by scalafiddle). I removed all compiler plugins and compiler options from my build file. Interestingly enough, scalafiddle compiles the snippet...

Comment: @MatthiasLanger Oh, you need `-Ypartial-unification`. I edited the answer to note this.